# GIS ArcMap 10.7 Layers have different scale and cant stack together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, overlapping-features

I am using Windows 10 system and ArcMap 10.7.

I have three layers, A, B, C. I tend to stack these three layers, the order should be A on B on C. I can put A on C, but I cannot put B on C. I thought this should be a coordinate system problem. However, they are using the same coordinate system. I found a clue about the problem that the A B layers have a different scale with C layer.

[image]

[image]

I wonder if a different scale cause the problem.

Note:
example of the ABC layers: A could be shops in a city. B could be like a city. C could be like a state.

Could anyone know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the data with a defined coordinate system do not overlap properly, this means that there is something wrong with the data. Coordinates are absolute values and, while the scale to see the whole extent of a city is different to the scale to see a country, they should stack properly.

Your scale of 1:0.81 is strange for a dataset, except if you zoom in instead of displaying its full extent. So I would assume that A and B are correct, but not C. You could check from online layer if this is the case (they should all stack with any base layer). So you have two ways to fix that 1) delete/rename the prj file of your C shapefile and try to find its correct coordinate system (look at coordinate values to guess if it is in geographic coordinates (values between -180 and + 180) or XY coordinates (usually much larger values). 2) start an edit session and modify the coordinates of your file with the "spatial adjusment tool". For both methods, keep a copy of your original file.

Comment: Thank you. I download the same data from other sources. The layer C has  problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling the polygon.

1. Add Scale tool to the toolbar: click Customize tab in ArcMap --> Customize Mode --> Commands --> in Editor Category, find Scale, and drag and drop it to Editor toolbar.
2. Start Editing session on the target feature layer.
3. Use the Edit tool on the Editor toolbar to highlight the target feature.
4. Click the Scale tool, press the F key on the keyboard. The Scale factor pop-up shows up.
5. Calculate the scale factor: the **scale factor is the square root of the area ration**: (B/A)^(1/2), **A is the original area, and B is the area to increase/decrease** too.
6. The area can easily be calculated using the calculate geometry by adding a new field in the attribute table, Note:- Polygon layers must follow PCS(linear units).
7. Enter the Scale factor and press Enter. The polygon will be scaled to the target size.

[Click here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/editing-existing-features/scaling-a-feature.htm) to know how scaling works in ArcMap.